# strtotime -> NSDate

Tags: cocoa, nsdate, foundation

is there a way to convert [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php)-like Strings (e.g.: '-3 days' with a given date) with NSDate?

Answer (score 1):

See NSDate's [+dateWithNaturalLanguageString:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000188-dateWithNaturalLanguageString_). I'm not sure how much "natural language" is supported (such as the "-3 days" example you give), but it's your best bet.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help. Looks like I need to implement correct datetime calculations on my own. Thanks anyway =)